# How much memory is used in the following C program?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

Suppose int size is 4 bytes. 
Following the Code snippet in C, how much bytes is requested to store the variables? 
* I read that some can be stored in the registers / stack, but I asked for the total size, therefore it doesn't matter.

```
{
    int a,b;
    {
        int c; 
    }
    {
        int d, e;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing if they are not used. Depends on the compilation flags.

Comment: Assuming nothing is optimized away because it is not used, then variable `d` (or `e`) may use the same memory location as `c`. (Or it may not, as per the compiler's Divine insights).

Comment: This question is only meaningful (1) for large objects/arrays (2) that are actually used or whose addresses spill to external calls. Otherwise call frame overhead and temporary spills will dominate and there's no reason to assume they use *any* memory.

Answer (score 2):

You should not care, and it depends *a lot* upon the [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags and the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

A variable could stay *entirely* in a [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), and then it does not consume memory (and sometimes it does not appear in the generated machine code, because the compiler figured out that it is useless). But read about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and call frames and [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation). Of course, a common sense rule is to avoid huge call frames (e.g. avoid declaring very large [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) such as `double hugelocalarr[1000000];`). A reasonable call frame should (in general) be at most a kilobyte or a few of them (often, the total call stack should not exceed a megabyte or a few of them, and you need to think about recursive functions or deeply nested calls).

In practice, if you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), look into the [command options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) such as `-Wstack-usage=`X (use it with various optimization flags, such as `-O1` or `-O2` ...) etc... You'll get warnings about functions using a lot of stack (more than X bytes).

Be also aware of [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Recent compilers are sometimes able to cleverly optimize them. And think also of [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). Compilers are able to do that when optimizing (even *without* any `inline` keyword).

Read the [*C is not a low-level language*](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3212479) paper by David Chisnall.